# webpack Error :Module parse failed You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I want extract and compile css code from sass file with extract-text-webpack-plugin , but webpack give me this Error :

```
ERROR in ./style.scss
Module parse failed: H:\projects\new\app\style.scss Unexpected token (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| body{
|   background-color: #d9534f;
| }
 @ ./index.js 2:0-22
```

my version of webpack and extract-text-webpack-plugin :

```
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
"webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.22"
```

my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
let ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
let extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('test.css');

module.exports = {
    context:path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loader: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
            , {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                loader: extractCSS.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader!sass-loader' })
    }
            , {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff'
}, {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader'
}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')+'/index.html',
        inject: 'body'
    })
]
};
```

and my simple .scss  file :

```
body{
  background-color: #d9534f;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve it :

```
 module: {
        loaders: [
            {
```

instead of

```
 module: {
        loader: [
            {
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me this way.

Add `const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");` in the top.

and add this to loaders:

```
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader!sass-loader'}),
    },
```

Comment: I try , but give me this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Answer (score -1):

here you go buddy

```
{ test: /\.sass$/, use: extractText.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader!sass-loader' }) }
```